# PHP POST array clearing after button clicked

Tags: php, post, switch-statement

I have code in a switch case and in the same case statement I have the code below:

```
if(isset($_POST['dropsubmit'])) {
  var_dump($_POST);
  formGen($pdo, 'categories');
  $pk = $_POST['category'];
  echo $pk;
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
  echo $pk;
```

When I echo $pk or $_POST['category'] the webpage tells me the variable has not been declared. How do I store the post variable to a globally seen variable to use in the second IF statement?

Comment: `$_POST` should be global already. Sounds like `$_POST['dropsubmit']` is set but `$_POST['category']` or `$_POST['submit']` is not set. What is the var_dump of `$_POST`?

Comment: When $_POST['dropsubmit'] is clicked, `var_dump($_POST)` is `'category' => string 'Whatever' and 'dropsubmit' => string 'Submit'`. When $_POST['submit'] is clicked, `var_dump($_POST)` is `'name' (name of the textfield) => string '' and 'submit' => string 'Submit'`, so it doesn't even see $_POST['category'] in the second var_dump

Answer (score 0):

$_POST variables are always globally visible. If the variable has not been declared that means that you did not receive it from client browser in POST request or the request was GET request.

$_POST variables are copied from POST request header which client browser sent. They are generated again whenever client refreshes the page.

Enter developer mode in your browser from which you are accessing this web page. Make sure that request type is POST and that browser sets `category` POST variable by looking at request headers.

Comment: How do I enter developer mode and view the request headers please?

Comment: Which browser are you using? For Opera and Chrome open your page, press CTRL+SHIFT+i. Then go to "Network" tab.

Comment: Chrome, sorry should've said

Comment: :)  open your page, press CTRL+SHIFT+i, then go to "Network" tab. And refresh the page. Click on the item you are interested in and then go to tab "Headers". "Request Method" should be POST. At the bottom, "Form Data" shows POST variables your browser is sending to your page.

Comment: When the first button is clicked 'category' is received in $_POST but then is lost as soon as the second button is clicked...

Comment: Well the problem is that you posted only part of the code and anyone can just guess what is happening in your program. I suppose that first button causes POST request to be triggered with 'category' variable present. When the second button is clicked, the form for which second button is POST-ing should also contain 'category' variable. 
Sorry, you need to provide more code and/or explanation how your program should behave.